# Daniel and Scott are playing a game where a player wins as soon as he has two points more than his opponent. Both players start at par,and points are…

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

The question asks

Daniel and Scott are playing a game where a player wins as soon as he has two points
more than his opponent. Both players start at par, and points are earned one at a
time. If Daniel has a 60% chance of winning each point, what is the probability that
he will win the game?

The solutions states:

Consider the situation after two points. Daniel has a $9/25$ chance of winning, Scott,
$4/25$, and there is a $12/25$ chance that the players will be tied. In the latter case, we
revert to the original situation. In particular, after every two points, either the game returns to the original situation, or one player wins. If it is given that the game lasts
$2k$ rounds, then the players must be at par after $2(k −1)$ rounds, and then Daniel wins
with probability $\frac{\frac{9}{25}}{\frac{9}{25}+\frac{4}{25}}= \frac{9}{13}$. Since this holds for any k, we conclude
that Daniel wins the game with probability $9/13$.

While i am convinced the answer is $9/13$ i'm not convinced the arguement they have presented is mathematically watertight as they've assumed that the game ends in $2k$ rounds. Perhaps a better arguement would be let $D$ be the event that Daniel wins the game, and $W_{2k}$ be the event that the game is won in $2k$ rounds then it follows that

$$\mathbb{P}(D)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(D \cap W_{2k})$$ and so $$\mathbb{P}(D)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{25}\left(\frac{12}{25}\right)^{2(k-1)}$$ hence $\mathbb{P}(D)=\frac{9/25}{1-12/25}=\frac{9}{13}$.

Now i could calculate the conditional probability that they did and use it in the calculation of $\mathbb{P}(D \cap W_{2k})$ but that seems rather long winded. So my question is whether or not their proof is written formally and if not what would be point in calculating $\mathbb{P}(D|W_{2K})$? Would someone be able to include it in a formal proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W_{2k}$ be the event that the game ends in $2k$ rounds and let $U_{2k}$ denote the event that they are at par after $2k$ rounds. Then what they say is that
$$
P(U_{2(k-1)}\mid W_{2k})=1
$$
so that
$$
P(D\mid W_{2k})=P(D\mid U_{2(k-1)})
$$
and thus
$$
\begin{align}
P(D)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(D\cap W_{2k})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{P(W_{2k})}\underbrace{P(D\mid U_{2(k-1)})}_{9/13}\\
&=\frac{9}{13}\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(W_{2k})}_1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer to your question but a shorter route here. It is not really necessary to look at further rounds and practicize infinite sums.

If $p$ is the probability that Daniel wins then we have the equality:
$$p=\frac{3}{5}\frac{3}{5}+\left(\frac{3}{5}\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2}{5}\frac{3}{5}\right)p$$ leading directly to: $$p=\frac{9}{13}$$

Comment: That is a neat way to put it!